# Border bottom doesn't show below an image but shows up below text in the same div

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css

I have a div element with an image and a text on the side. I need both image and text to have a bottom border. However, the border only appears below the text and not the image.  Below is my template and CSS. Am I missing something, can you point me to any solution?

```
<div class="header">
   <img class="local-image" src="assets/icons/local-icon.svg">
   <div class="pt-4 text-sm">
      <h4>Image Label</h4>
      <p>{{ imageDetails.name }} </p>
   </div> 
</div>


.header {
        @apply relative mx-9 border-b border-solid border-nobel;
}

.local-image {
         @apply absolute top-4 -left-11;      
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the image is covering the border? You can try adding some extra padding.

Comment: Can you show any other styles that are being added to .header and children, please?

Comment: The image is not covering the border, even when I moved the image towards the top, there is still no border at the bottom @OctavianMărculescu

Comment: @DanielGuzman There isn't any more style, just the style for the image which I edited to the question.

Comment: @ShrawaniSilwal If you learn to use your browsers inspector and you'll be able to solve issues like this =)

Answer (score 1):

I see you're applying class `-left-11` because the image overlaps the text, but with this what you're doing is *pulling* the image out of the container (.header). If you inspect the box, you'll notice it.

For your current code, the quickest solution is to **not** move the image out of its container, but take it to the left border, and add some left padding to the container.

```
.header {
    @apply relative mx-9 border-b border-solid border-nobel pl-11;
}

.local-image {
    @apply absolute top-4 left-0;      
}
```

Notice the `pl-11` on `.header` and the `left-0` on `.local-image`. Whe're just not moving the image to the left out of it's container but sticking it to the left border, and instead, to solve the overlapping, applying that **11** (tailwind... "points" or somethign) as container's padding left.

Comment: This works perfectly, the image was indeed being pulled out of the container. Thank you .